# ogr2ogr cannot open datasource ogrinfo can open

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, ogr, pbf

I've got a random .osm.pbf from Geofabrik which I'm trying to extract a small region of:

```sh
$ ogr2ogr -f OSM -spat 7 48 8 49 data/osm/extract.osm.pbf data/osm/germany-latest.osm.pbf
ERROR 1: OSM driver does not support data source creation
```

The same file opens fine using ogrinfo:

```sh
ogrinfo data/osm/germany.osm.pbf points
INFO: Open of `data/osm/germany.osm.pbf'
      using driver `OSM' successful.

Layer name: points
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: -1
Extent: (5.864417, 47.265430) - (15.050780, 55.147770)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
osm_id: String (0.0)
name: String (0.0)
barrier: String (0.0)
highway: String (0.0)
ref: String (0.0)
address: String (0.0)
is_in: String (0.0)
place: String (0.0)
man_made: String (0.0)
other_tags: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(points):100
  osm_id (String) = 100
  other_tags (String) = "description"=>"Weltkriegsdenkmal","historic"=>"memorial","memorial"=>"war_memorial"
  POINT (10.8340913 52.8916184)

OGRFeature(points):122317
  osm_id (String) = 122317
  name (String) = Hamburg
  other_tags (String) = "TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:Class"=>"Point","TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:Direction"=>"positive","TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:LCLversion"=>"8.00","TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:LocationCode"=>"10696","TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:NextLocationCode"=>"10697","TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:PrevLocationCode"=>"10695","traffic_sign"=>"city_limit"
  POINT (10.0232716 53.5282633)

OGRFeature(points):122329
  osm_id (String) = 122329
  other_tags (String) = "TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:Class"=>"Point","TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:Direction"=>"positive","TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:LCLversion"=>"8.00","TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:LocationCode"=>"35609","TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:PrevLocationCode"=>"53868"
  POINT (10.0310127 53.5374933)

OGRFeature(points):122350
  osm_id (String) = 122350
  name (String) = Michaeliskirche
  other_tags (String) = "bus"=>"yes","network"=>"HVV","public_transport"=>"stop_position"
  POINT (9.9786134 53.5492333)

OGRFeature(points):122351
  osm_id (String) = 122351
  highway (String) = crossing
  other_tags (String) = "bicycle"=>"yes","button_operated"=>"yes","crossing"=>"traffic_signals","tactile_paving"=>"no","traffic_signals:sound"=>"yes","traffic_signals:vibration"=>"yes"
  POINT (9.977553 53.5492951)
```

(output cut)

When using SHP as output format, I also get an error:

```sh
$ ogr2ogr -f OSM -spat 7 48 8 49 data/osm/extract.shp data/osm/germany-latest.osm.pbf points
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `data/osm/germany-latest.osm.pbf' with the following drivers.
  -> `FITS'
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `netCDF'
  -> `PDS4'
  -> `VICAR'
  -> `JP2OpenJPEG'
  -> `PDF'
  -> `MBTiles'
  -> `BAG'
  -> `EEDA'
  -> `OGCAPI'
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'
  -> `MapInfo File'
  -> `UK .NTF'
  -> `LVBAG'
  -> `OGR_SDTS'
  -> `S57'
  -> `DGN'
  -> `OGR_VRT'
  -> `REC'
  -> `Memory'
  -> `CSV'
  -> `NAS'
  -> `GML'
  -> `GPX'
  -> `LIBKML'
  -> `KML'
  -> `GeoJSON'
  -> `GeoJSONSeq'
  -> `ESRIJSON'
  -> `TopoJSON'
  -> `Interlis 1'
  -> `Interlis 2'
  -> `OGR_GMT'
  -> `GPKG'
  -> `SQLite'
  -> `ODBC'
  -> `WAsP'
  -> `PGeo'
  -> `MSSQLSpatial'
  -> `OGR_OGDI'
  -> `PostgreSQL'
  -> `MySQL'
  -> `OpenFileGDB'
  -> `DXF'
  -> `CAD'
  -> `FlatGeobuf'
  -> `Geoconcept'
  -> `GeoRSS'
  -> `GPSTrackMaker'
  -> `VFK'
  -> `PGDUMP'
  -> `OSM'
  -> `GPSBabel'
  -> `OGR_PDS'
  -> `WFS'
  -> `OAPIF'
  -> `SOSI'
  -> `Geomedia'
  -> `EDIGEO'
  -> `SVG'
  -> `CouchDB'
  -> `Cloudant'
  -> `Idrisi'
  -> `ARCGEN'
  -> `XLS'
  -> `ODS'
  -> `XLSX'
  -> `Elasticsearch'
  -> `Walk'
  -> `Carto'
  -> `AmigoCloud'
  -> `SXF'
  -> `Selafin'
  -> `JML'
  -> `PLSCENES'
  -> `CSW'
  -> `VDV'
  -> `GMLAS'
  -> `MVT'
  -> `NGW'
  -> `MapML'
  -> `TIGER'
  -> `AVCBin'
  -> `AVCE00'
  -> `HTTP'
```

I see the same behaviour with the decompressed .osm file.

What am I doing wrong ? I have GDAL version 3.4.1, Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error on your second attempt doesn't make sense if this is the issue, but one mistake you made is that `-f` declares *output* file format, not input. So if you're meaning to convert to SHP, you'll want to use `-f ESRI Shapefile` instead of `-f OSM`.

Comment: Ahhhh … it's for output, not input … I didn't know that, thanks ! :)

Comment: You can leave off the `-f` parameter in modern GDAL to have it guess the format from the filename.

Answer (score 3):

The error is not about opening but about creating the `data/osm/extract.osm.pbf` file.

GDAL cannot create new OSM PBF files.

Best use a tool like `osmium` for this.

Comment: Getting an error when outputting to SHP too … (see the question)